# FCM Remote Message data is empty when received in flutter

Tags: laravel, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When trying to send a push notification to my flutter application from my laravel application it receives the title and body but any additional data I add to the data tag in the array does not come in with it and it shows as empty.

How I am sending the notification through laravel

```
$header[] = 'Content-type: application/json';
$header[] = 'Authorization: key=' . env('FCM_LEGACY_KEY');

$payload = [
    'priority' => 'high',
    'content_available' => true,
    'to' => $fcm,
    'notification' => [
        'body' => trim($msg),
        'title' => trim($title),
    ],
    'data' => [
        'click_action' => 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
        'page' => $page,
        'id' => $id
    ],
];


$crl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send');
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($payload));

curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$rest = curl_exec($crl);
curl_close($crl);
```

How I am trying to receive it in flutter

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {

  Map<String, dynamic> json = message.data; 

  print('Got a message whilst in the foreground!');


  print('Message data base: ${message.data}');

  print('Message data page: ${message.data['page']}');

  print('Message data json page: ${json['page']}');


  print('Message data summaryId: ${message.data['id']}');
  PushNotification notification = PushNotification(
    title: message.notification?.title,
    body: message.notification?.body,

  );
```

Comment: Found the issue was due to my laravel project. I have it sending out the notifications through a jobs file and did not realize I had to restart my queue to reflect the changes in my job file. Able to receive data after restarting the queue

Comment: Good to hear you figured it out @poomulus. I'm voting to close the question as an ephemeral problem/mistake, as those in the same situation are unlikely to be helped by any answer that may be posted here.